# Ruby how to remove a more than one space character?

Tags: ruby, string, whitespace

**Ruby**
Okay, I want to remove a more than one space character in a strings if there's any. What I mean is, let's say I have a text like this:

```
I want to     learn ruby more and more.
```

See there's a more than one space character after "to" and before "learn" either it a tab or just a several spaces. Now what I want is, how can I know if there's something like this in a text file, and I want to make it just one space per word or string. So it will become like this

```
I want to learn ruby more and more.
```

Can I use Gsub? or do I need to use other method? I tried Gsub, but can't figure out how to implement it the right way so it can produce the result I want. Hopefully I explained it clear. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `str.split(" ").join(" ")` also works, but methods that operate on the string directly are more efficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to replace one or more whitespace (regex `/ +/`) to a single whitespace:

```
'I want to     learn ruby more and more.'.gsub(/ +/, " ")
#=> "I want to learn ruby more and more."
```

Answer (score 12):

[String#squeeze](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-squeeze) remove runs of more than one character:

```
'I want to     learn ruby more and more.'.squeeze(' ')
# => "I want to learn ruby more and more."
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to remove whitespaces and replace them with single " "

```
" Bring   ME \n the   Horizon".squish
# => "Bring ME the Horizon"

%{ Multi-line
   string }.squish                   # => "Multi-line string"

" foo   bar    \n   \t   boo".squish # => "foo bar boo"
```

https://apidock.com/rails/String/squish

Comment: this is perfect, should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to remove all whitespace from a string, including **spaces** and also **tabs**. I use this for stripping whitespace from email addresses on login fields.

```
'   I want to   learn ruby more and more.'.gsub(/\s/,"")
# => "Iwanttolearnrubymoreandmore."
```

The `/\s/` matches any whitespace character including **tabs**, whereas `/ +/` won't.